# How to expand path from given argument using regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, command-line

I'm working on a simple search tool. It searches through source code files in directory defined by command line argument, for example:

```
finder 'path' 'keyword'
```

I have difficulties with how to properly transform given argument to a path string which I can use in **Dir.chdir(path)**. Here is what I mean, according to my logic I have 4 distinct cases:

- .  (just current directory)
- /folder
- ./folder
- ~/Desktop/folder

Here is what I have now:

```
def expand_path(path)
  case path
  when '.'
   return '.'
  when /\/[a-z]*/.match(path)
   return Dir.pwd + path
  when /\.\/[a-z]*/.match(path)
   return Dir.pwd + path[1..-1]
  when /~(\/[a-zA-Z\w]*)+/.match(path)
   return File.expand_path(path, __FILE__)
  else
   puts "Wrong path name"
  end
end
```

I am not sure if there is a better approach, this is what I came up with.
Still, my approach doesn't work. I'm not sure if there is a problem with regex or with something else. I'm a newcomer in Ruby world so, may be I just made some silly mistake.

[SOLVED]

```
  def expand_path(path)
   case path
   when '.'
     return '.'
   when /~(\/[a-zA-Z\w]*)+/
     return File.expand_path(path, __FILE__)    
   when /\.\/[a-z]*/
     return Dir.pwd + path[1..-1]
   when /\/[a-z]*/
     return Dir.pwd + path

   else
     puts "Wrong path name"
   end
  end
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have to segregate the different inputs. Also, if I give you an absolute path ("/folder"), I mean an absolute path:  it is wrong to decide to add something to the beginning of it.

Comment: Your `when` expressions can be simpler: `when /\/[a-z]*/` is sufficient. You already specify the string to match against with `case path`

Comment: You don't need any of the `return`s in [SOLVED].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thpugh as you say the issue has been solved, there is at least 1 point that can be improved in your regular expressions, namely `[a-zA-Z\w]` can be just replaced with mere `\w` as it already includes `a-zA-Z`.

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html):

> \w stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters
>   [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.

Also, your last `when` contains `/\/[a-z]*/` regex that also matches just `/`. If that is what you want, OK, if not, replace `*` with `+`. The same is with `/\.\/[a-z]*/` - it will match `./`. If you want to match `./` + at least 1 character, you need to replace adterisk with a plus.

So, I suggest:

```
def expand_path(path)
   case path
   when '.'
     return '.'
   when /~(\/\w*)+/
     return File.expand_path(path, __FILE__)    
   when /\.\/[a-z]+/
     return Dir.pwd + path[1..-1]
   when /\/[a-z]+/
     return Dir.pwd + path

   else
     puts "Wrong path name"
   end
  end
```